# Alternating Least Square parameters tuning

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, least-squares, hyperparameters, collaborative-filtering

Context: I am working an building a recommender system using implicit feedback (orders) using the implicit library in python.

Issue: when trying to tune the parameters in order to know the best parameters to use, the output is not looping over all variables, and is not calculating the auc. How can I make sure it loops over all combination, and add in the dictionary if the combinations lead to a highest AUC score ?
Also, please feel free to let me know if there is a library that I can use to tune it as I did not know how to use gridsearchCV for example for this use case (ALS model).

In the code:
training_set2 - The altered version of the original training_set with a certain percentage of the user-item pairs that originally had interaction set back to zero.

validation_set - A copy of the original training_set matrix, unaltered, so it can be used to see how the rank order compares with the actual interactions.

Expected output: Is a dictionary with all the combinations, in a desc order with the last one being the combination that has the highest AUC score. This combination will be the one I will use for my test set.

```
    def auc_score(predictions, test):
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(test, predictions)
        return metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)

    def calc_mean_auc(training_set, altered_users, predictions, test_set):
        '''
        This function will calculate the mean AUC by user for any user that had their user-item matrix altered. 
        '''
        store_auc = [] # An empty list to store the AUC for each user that had an item removed from the training set
        item_vecs = predictions[1]
        for user in altered_users: # Iterate through each user that had an item altered
            training_row = training_set[user,:].toarray().reshape(-1) # Get the training set row
            zero_inds = np.where(training_row == 0) # Find where the interaction had not yet occurred
            # Get the predicted values based on our user/item vectors
            user_vec = predictions[0][user,:]
            pred = user_vec.dot(item_vecs).toarray()[0,zero_inds].reshape(-1)
            # Get only the items that were originally zero
            # Select all ratings from the MF prediction for this user that originally had no iteraction
            actual = test_set[user,:].toarray()[0,zero_inds].reshape(-1) 
            # Select the binarized yes/no interaction pairs from the original full data
            # that align with the same pairs in training 
            store_auc.append(auc_score(pred, actual)) # Calculate AUC for the given user and store
        # End users iteration

        return float('%.3f'%np.mean(store_auc)) 
    ...
    latent_factors = [5, 10, 20, 40, 80]
    regularizations = [0.01, 0.1, 1., 10., 100.]
    regularizations.sort()
    iter_array = [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]

    best_params = {}
    best_params['n_factors'] = latent_factors[0]
    best_params['reg'] = regularizations[0]
    best_params['n_iter'] = 0
    best_params['auc_result'] = np.inf
    best_params['model'] = None

    for fact in latent_factors:
        print('Factors: {}'.format(fact))
        for reg in regularizations:
            print ('Regularization: {}'.format(reg))
            for ite in iter_array:
                print ('Iteration: {}'.format(ite))
                model = implicit.als.AlternatingLeastSquares(
                    factors=fact,
                    regularization=reg, 
                    iterations=ite)



    model.fit((training2_set.T * 15).astype('double'))
                customers_vecs = model.user_factors
                restaurant_vecs = model.item_factors
                auc_result = calc_mean_auc(training2_set, cust_altered2, 
                  [sparse.csr_matrix(customers_vecs), sparse.csr_matrix(restaurant_vecs.T)], validation_set)
                if auc_result > best_params['auc_result']:
                    best_params['n_factors'] = fact
                    best_params['reg'] = reg
                    best_params['n_iter'] = ite
                    best_params['auc_result'] = auc_result
                    best_params['model'] = 'AlternatingLeastSquare'
                    print ('New optimal hyperparameters')
                    print (pd.Series(best_params))
```

I cannot post a picture but this is the output that I get:

```
</b>
Factors: 5</b>
Regularization: 0.01</b>
Iteration: 1</b>

n_factors     5.00</b>
reg           0.01</b>
n_iter        0.00</b>
auc_result     inf</b>
model          NaN</b>
dtype: float64</b>
Iteration: 2</b>

n_factors     5.00</b>
reg           0.01</b>
n_iter        0.00</b>
auc_result     inf</b>
model          NaN</b>
dtype: float64</b>
Iteration: 5</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only keeping the *best* parameters - `if auc_error < best_params['auc_error']:`

Use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accumulate all the parameters in lists

```
...
from collections import defaultdict
best_params = defaultdict(list)
##best_params = {}
##best_params['n_factors'] = latent_factors[0]
##best_params['reg'] = regularizations[0]
##best_params['n_iter'] = 0
##best_params['auc_error'] = np.inf
##best_params['model'] = None
...
for fact in latent_factors:
    ...
        ...
            ##if auc_error < best_params['auc_error']:
            best_params['n_factors'].append(fact)
            best_params['reg'].append(reg)
            best_params['n_iter'].append(ite)
            best_params['auc_error'].append(auc_error)
            best_params['model'].append('AlternatingLeastSquare')
            ##print ('New optimal hyperparameters')
```

---

It appears you are using Pandas so make a DataFrame and sort it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(best_params)
df = df.sort_values('auc_error')
```